# ssh port forward

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I wanna connect to a group of machines using a specific machine using ssh tunneling. But in all solutions found, I need to specify a entry per machine in my ssh config file. I would like to use a wildcard in this way:

```
   Host *.mydomain.com
   // some magic here
```

For now, the best solution found was:

http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/11/27/advanced-ssh-configuration-and-tunneling-we-dont-need-no-stinking-vpn-software/

Comment: Does the tunnel server allow executing commands (specifically `netcat`, `nc` and/or `socat`), or is it strictly tunneling-only?

Comment: yes! it can execute commands!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run programs such as `nc` or `netcat` or `socat` on your tunnel server, you could use a `ProxyCommand` instead of a port forward:

```
# Only necessary if it matches the *.mydomain.com wildcard. Useless otherwise.
Host tunnelbox.mydomain.com
    ProxyCommand none

Host *.mydomain.com
    ProxyCommand ssh tunnelbox.mydomain.com nc %h %p
    #ProxyCommand ssh tunnelbox.mydomain.com ncat %h %p
    #ProxyCommand ssh tunnelbox.mydomain.com socat stdio tcp:%h:%p
    #ProxyCommand ssh tunnelbox.mydomain.com netcat %h %p
```

Uncomment the apropriate ProxyCommand, depending on what tools the tunnel server has installed.

---

Note that this will set up and tear down a separate SSH connection for every tunnel established, which means connecting will be slower than via SOCKS. (It won't affect performance *after* connection, however.)

If your SSH version supports it, you could enable connection multiplexing:

```
Host tunnelbox.mydomain.com
    ControlMaster no
    ControlPath none

Host *.mydomain.com
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%l.%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist 10m
```